# Enable word wrap for latex files only in vscode

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

I want Visual Studio Code to "word wrap" latex files automatically, but leave other files as they are. How do I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [Language-specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings). Add the following block in your user settings.

```
"[latex]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
},
```

To do this, open the command pallette (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>shift</kbd> - <kbd>p</kbd>), select `Preferences: Configure language specific settings...` and select the latex language.

[image: configure language specific settings...]